# How to match programmatically the member mentioned in the build error CS0122 to the actual method on the culprit type?

Tags: c#, roslyn, static-code-analysis

Consider the following error message:

> error CS0122: 'wbpoc_Base.IsNullColumnValue(DataRow, string)' is inaccessible due to its protection level

As a human I know the problem is with this method:

```
private static bool IsNullColumnValue(DataRow row, String columnName)
{
    return (string.IsNullOrEmpty(columnName) || row[columnName] == DBNull.Value);
}
```

But is there a straightforward way to match `wbpoc_Base.IsNullColumnValue(DataRow, string)` to the actual signature programmatically when the error message mangles the actual signature of that method - it converts `String` to the respective built-in type `string` and omits the names of the parameters?

Right now it seems the code will have to "massage" the signatures of the type by:

- Removing the parameter names
- Translating built-in type names to their canonical form

I hope these are the only translations that must be done.

I wish there was a flag to the compiler that would turn off any translations and keep the references to code elements exactly as written in the source code.

Maybe there is something like that?

**EDIT**

This "massaging" is a nightmare, because of the generic types. I assume the error would output `List<string>` instead of `List<String>`. Oh man ...

**EDIT 1**

I am building a tool to automate code refactoring. One of the commands is to move functions from a class to another. The goal is to reduce manual intervention as much as possible. Once the functions are moved the tool runs the build and examines the errors. The errors are parsed and acted upon automatically. So, it is very important to be able to match the errors to actual code.

**EDIT 2**

A clarification on what I am trying to achieve. I have collected the CS error messages and now want to act on them automatically. It is possible, because I know the code fails compilation because of my changes and I know exactly what changes are these. I have at my disposal:

1. Error messages
2. Roslyn API to parse the source code and build Syntax and Semantic models.
3. Binary code from the previous build in case I need it.

The problem is correlating error messages to the artifacts of the Roslyn API. The example of an error message above references

```
wbpoc_Base.IsNullColumnValue(DataRow, string)
```

but the actual source code declares

```
IsNullColumnValue(DataRow row, String columnName)
```

And if we read the metadata using Mono.Cecil it would return a `MethodDefinition` object with the `FullName` of

```
System.Boolean The.Namespace.Of.wbpoc_Base::IsNullColumnValue(System.Data.DataRow, System.String)
```

As we can see, all the 3 representations denote the same code element - a method in the `wbpoc_Base` class. But they are not immediately comparable - we have to normalize them into some canonical form.

I can understand about `Mono.Cecil` - it is a non Microsoft product. But Roslyn API and C# compiler are produced by the same team or closely related teams, no? Surely there is value in being able to correlate **programmatically** code elements mentioned in the error messages with the respective Syntax nodes produced by the Roslyn API.

The problem is that one has to "massage" the code element references from the errors, because they are not always usable directly, as my example shows.

That brings me to wonder whether there is a way to produce error messages with more faithful code references.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you're trying to do?

Comment: See **EDIT 1**.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler diagnostics (error, warning, information) have the information of the location of the text where the diagnostic has been reported.

This information can be collected in a `SARIF` file when using the `ErrorLog` `MSBuild` property or the `-errorlog` compiler argument.

- [SARIF Home](http://sarifweb.azurewebsites.net/)
- [C# Compiler Options to report errors and warnings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/errors-warnings)

Comment: I have no problems collecting error messages. I have a problem with their format. Are you saying that passing `-errorlog` not only collects the errors, but also formats them differently? To clarify - I have no problem collecting error messages, I have problem with the format of some, for example - CS0122

Comment: I'm not aware of any extra metadata added to compiler errors. But you can collect the error log and check for yourself.

Comment: So, I ran msbuild with error collection and have not noticed anything special. Can you provide more details? Because so far I am failing to understand the relevance of your answer. I must be missing something.

Comment: Maybe it's I that am missing something. It's not very clear what you're asking.

Comment: See **EDIT 2**.